# Does "docker build --no-cache" pull new version of base images?

Tags: docker

Does docker `build --no-cache <args>` pull new version of base image (e.g. `--pull`) or it's only disabling caching of Dockerfile commands?

Background:

I have multistage build where one of the source images is local only. The `--pull` option cannot be used in this case. Question is if `--no-cache` will force the pulling of remote base images.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that won’t automatically pull, but I’m also pretty sure (even if it would) that nothing bad would happen if you tried it; it won’t delete the preexisting image even if it can’t pull an updated one.

Comment: I tried it, but I was not sure if it's doing the pull or not. Right now all my local images have matching hash with what is available in repository. I will create a test setup for this and post the result...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `--no-cache` will not result in a new pull of the base image.